# How to read text file without the headline into ArrayList

Tags: java, csv

I'm currently working on an assignment and I cannot find any clue to remove the headline from the text file and write the rest into an ArrayList. Can someone help me?

```
ID,Nama,GajiPokok,JmlAbsensi,JmlIzin

2,Peter,5000000,17,3
1,John,4500000,19,1
3,Linda,10000000,13,7
4,Lucy,7000000,20,0
```

Here is my code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\" + args[0] + ".txt"));
try {
    String line = in.readLine();
    String data[];
    while (line != null){
        data = line.split(",");
        Staff s = new Staff(){};
        s.setID(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
        s.setNama(data[1]);
        s.setGajiPokok(Long.parseLong(data[2]));
        s.setjmlhAbsensi(Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
        s.setjmlhIzin(Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
        
        s.getID();
        s.getNama();
        s.getGajiPokok();
        s.getjmlhAbsensi();
        s.getjmlhIzin();
       
        list_Staff.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
        line = in.readLine();
    }
    in.close(); 
}   catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore first line while reading the CSV file then you can simple skip processing of 1st line by calling `in.readLine();` twice at the start as shown in below example:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\" + args[0] + ".txt"));
String line = in.readLine();
line = in.readLine(); //skip fist line and read second line
String data[];
while (line != null){
    data = line.split(",");
    Staff s = new Staff(){};
    s.setID(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
    s.setNama(data[1]);
    s.setGajiPokok(Long.parseLong(data[2]));
    s.setjmlhAbsensi(Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
    s.setjmlhIzin(Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
     
    s.getID();
    s.getNama();
    s.getGajiPokok();
    s.getjmlhAbsensi();
    s.getjmlhIzin();
      
    list_Staff.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
    line = in.readLine();
}
```

Using `skip()` method of JAVA 8 Streams:

```
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\" + args[0] + ".txt"))) {
    Stream<String> lines = in.lines();
    List<Staff> staff = lines.skip(1).map(line -> {
        Staff s = new Staff();
        String data[] = line.split(",");
        s.setID(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
        s.setNama(data[1]);
        s.setGajiPokok(Long.parseLong(data[2]));
        s.setJmlhAbsensi(Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
        s.setJmlhIzin(Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
        return s;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(staff);
}
```

Comment: it works but i dont get it to my minds how it works, can you explain to me sir?, i'm bit curious how on earth it works, it just dont make any senses to my mind, but thankyou....

Comment: Here in.readLine() methods reads data line by line. When you call in.readLine() first time it will read first line, if you call it again then it will second line and so on. As you need to start processing from second line you just need to call in.readLine() twice in the beginning. Its same as when you read books. If you wish to skip first page then you will simply turn that page so that you will start reading book from second page. I hope i've explained it well :)

Comment: is there a way to remove those header without sskip it sir?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the following line twice or initialize integer variable and skip the loop if its zero.
String line = in.readLine();

Answer (score 0):

This solution works.

```
private void readTextFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    
    Stream<String> stream = in.lines();
    List<String> answer = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    // For Pre-Java8
    /*for (int i = 1; i < answer.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(answer.get(i));
    }*/
    // Split afterwards.
    
    Stream<String> ans = answer.stream().filter(p -> !p.equals(answer.get(0)));
    ans.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
}
```